# Microsoft Word 2016 gives security notice when pasting images into documents

Tags: microsoft-word, security, microsoft-office

I use Microsoft Word Professional Plus 2016.

Microsoft overnight updated Microsoft word and, each time I paste in a new picture into my documents, I get this message:

[image]

How do I stop this from occurring?

I went to

`File` --> `Options` --> `Trust Center` --> `Privacy Options`

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try in *Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations > Add new location…* to add the folder(s) where the documents are stored.

Comment: @harrymc Didn't work, which seems surprising. I added it, closed word, reopened and still get the same message.

Comment: You could try to uncheck all options under *Trust Center Settings > Protected View*, and also check the contents of *Trust Center Settings > File Block Settings*.

Comment: @harrymc that also didn't work :/ Could this be a bug on their end?

Comment: It could be some unfortunate setting. I don't have any more ideas except repairing Office (*Programs and Features*, right-click Office and *Change*) in both the suggested methods, or even uninstall plus reinstall.

Comment: It allows me to paste if I right click, go to paste options and click 'picture.' But won't work with just paste from keyboard.

Comment: Is there a way to set my paste setting so that I can automatically drop all the data that comes with the image?